# Excel VBA - on Multi Page Change but only once

Tags: excel, vba

I have a flexgrid within a Multipage under Main_Window.MultiPage2.Value = 2 this flexgrid has 8000 rows and I don't want those to load unless this page is actually clicked on. The code  I have does just that, but the problem is is that it loads every single time and not just once. Is there a way to make it load on the first change, and then that's it?

```
Private Sub MultiPage2_Change()

    If Main_Window.MultiPage2.Value = 2 Then
        Call form_segment_carrier_auto
    End If

End Sub
```

in form_segment_carrier_auto is a module that populates the flexgrid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you could declare a Public Boolean variable, for example:

```
Public ChangedOnce As Boolean
```

This should be in some standard code module.

Then change your event handler to:

```
Private Sub MultiPage2_Change()
    If ChangedOnce Then Exit Sub
    ChangedOnce = True
    If Main_Window.MultiPage2.Value = 2 Then
        Call form_segment_carrier_auto
    End If

End Sub
```

The event handler will still be called on multiple occasions if the event occurs on multiple occasions, but only the first call will do anything.

Comment: Works perfect, Originally placed the code inside hte user_form code and couldn't get it to work, but I placed the boolean inside a module, and the logic inside the sub itself and it works fine.

Comment: @JeffBeagley I've never completely understood the reason for it, but sometimes there are scope and/or lifetime issues when you try to declare public variables inside things like class modules or user-form code modules.